# How to use 'OpenCV' in ActionScript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, opencv

I would like to use OpenCV in my actionScript 3 code.

Is there a way to do so ?

I have a list of coordinates to draw a polygon on a mask,

and I need a way to grow the polygon and shrink it and also to add feather to it,

using OpenCV functions (I do not want to use AS3's 'scale').

Can this be done ?

Comment: it is possible to get data from other applications based on openCV (like ccv...which wouldnt really help, but it proves a point), but you cant directly implement openCV within flash. Maybe openCV isnt what you should be looking for? Not sure what you're trying to do exactly...

Comment: what I am trying to do is use OpenCV's functions to grow (expand) a polygon and apply feather to it...

Answer (score 0):

you can not use OpenCV in actionscript-3, because actionscript-3 is a advanced language, but openCV is made by C-language, it's a base language

Comment: If found [this port](http://www.francois-tarlier.com/blog/marilena-opencv-port-to-actionscript-3-as3-flash/) but is seems like the port is only for using OpenCV for 'Face Recognition' in Flash. but I want to use something much simpler that the OpenCV library supplies ...

Comment: With Alchemy you can port C libraries to AS3